# Laravel 5.1: How to set Route for update record

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am working with laravel 5.1

I am using the routes of laravel.

I used [Form/Html](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) for insert/update, but stuck in routing of update record.

Here is route for redirect to edit page in routes.php

```
Route::get('/company/edit/{id}','CompanyMasterController@edit');
```

In my CompanyMasterController.php

```
public function edit($id)
   {
      $company = CompanyMasters::find($id);

      return view('companymaster.edit',  compact('company'));
   }
```

My action in edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($company,['method' => 'PATCH','action'=>['CompanyMasterController@update','id'=>$company->id]]) !!}
```

and route for this action in routes.php

```
Route::put('/company/update/{id}','CompanyMasterController@update');
```

My controller action for update.

```
public function update($id)
   {
        $bookUpdate=Request::all();
        $book=  CompanyMasters::find($id);
        $book->update($bookUpdate);
        return redirect('/company/index');
   }
```

Now when I click on submit button it gives me:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Route::put is correct, the controller method is correct, but in the form you forgot to choose the right method - it is also 'PUT' not 'PATCH'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason you're getting this error is because you set your form to submit with a `PATCH` method and you've set your route to look for a `PUT` method.

The two initial options you have are either have the same method in your route file as your form or you could also set your route to:

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], '/company/update/{id}','CompanyMasterController@update');
```

The above will allow both methods to be used for that route.

---

Alternatively, you can use `route:resource()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers.

This will take care of all the basic Restful routes.

Then to take it one step further you can add the following to your routes file:

```
Route::model('company', 'App\CompanyMasters'); //make sure the namespace is correct if you're not using the standard `App\ModelName`
```

Then your resource route would look something like:

```
Route::resource('company', 'CompanyMasterController');
```

And then in `CompanyMasterController` your methods can be type hinted e.g.

```
public function edit($id) {...}
```

Would become:

```
public function edit(CompanyMaster $company)
{
    return view('companymaster.edit',  compact('company'));
}
```

Obviously, you don't have to go with this approach though if you don't want to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Jazz I've added an update to the answer if you want to take it one step further. Glad I could help!

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation. i also try this steps.